# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute Error

Tags: python

So I've been working on this game. I have 2 files, `Rooms.py` and `Monsters.py`. When I run `Rooms.py` the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Monster'` comes up. It's from the line `Monsters.Monster.create_monsters(self)` in the `create_loot_monsters` function. What is going on?

Bits of`Rooms.py`:

```
def create_15by15_rooms():
    roomlist = []
    for i in range(-7 ,8):
        e = -7
        i + 1
        for e in range(-7 ,8):
            room = Room(i - 1, e, [i - 1, e], [], [])
            e + 1
            roomlist.append(room)
            Room.create_loot_monsters(room)
    return roomlist

def create_loot_monsters(self):
    factor = random.randint(0, 100)
    if factor <= 20:
        pass
    elif factor > 20 and factor <= 50:
        pass  #loot room (function to generate loot)
    else:
        Monsters.Monster.create_monsters(self)

    return self
```

Bits of `Monsters.py`:

```
def create_monsters(self):
    num = random.randint(0,200)
    if num <= 20:
        self.monsters = Monster.Slime
    elif num > 20 and num <= 50:
        self.monsters = Monster.Zombie
    elif num > 50 and num <= 80:
        self.monsters = Monster.Skeleton
    elif num > 80 and num <= 120:
        self.monsters = Monster.Infected
    else: 
        self.monsters = Monster.Spirit
    return  self.monsters
```

EDIT: Imports from both: 
Rooms.py

```
import random
import Monsters
```

Monsters.py

```
import random
import Rooms
```

So what is going on? Why does the function not work?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This looks like an import problem. Can you edit your question to show the `import` lines in your code?

Comment: Your only show the `Monsters` module. What is `Monsters.Monsters`? Do you have a class called `Monsters` inside the `Monsters` module?

Comment: I have a class "Room" inside of Rooms.py and class "Monster" inside Monsters.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a circular import. `Rooms.py` imports from `Monsters.py`, but `Monsters.py` also imports from `Rooms.py`.

It's best to avoid circular imports like this. In the code you have shown, `Monsters.py` does not use anything from `Rooms.py`, so you should be able to fix the issue by removing the `import Rooms` import.

Note that the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests that you use lowercase for module names, e.g. `rooms.py` and `monsters.py`. This makes it easier to see the difference between your module `rooms` and your class `Room` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

change 
`Monsters.Monster.create_monsters(self)` to `Monsters.Monster.create_monsters()`
and it should work

checklist:

1 make sure the  Monsters.Monster.create_monsters() function accepts the instance of the the class from room.py

reasons:

> Monsters.Monster.create_monsters(self)

in this line seems you care calling the class function create_monsters.The parameter u r passing in is the entire class in the room.py(whatever that class is)
,while from the code Monster seems, you do not accept other parameters than the class it self.